# Spring MVC 400 Bad Request Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, jakarta-ee

Im getting 400 Bad Request on Ajax request all the time. I have no idea what's could go wrong with this. Im using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version> </dependency>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller("bookController")
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookControllerImpl implements BookController {

    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addBookToSystem(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
        return "book/newBook";
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Book addBookToSystem(@RequestBody Book book) {
        book.setBookStatus(BookStatus.AWAITING);
        return bookService.get(bookService.save(book));
    }
```

Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#addBook').submit(function(event) {

        var ISBN = $('#ISBN').val();
        var author = $('#author').val();
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var pages = $('#pages').val();
        var publicationYear = $('#publicationYear').val();
        var publisher = $('#publisher').val();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var json = { "ISBN" : ISBN, "author" : author, "description" : description, "pages" : pages, "publicationYear" : publicationYear, "publisher" : publisher, "title" : title };

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#addBook").attr("action"),
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(book) {
                var respContent = "";

                respContent += "<span class='success'>Dodano ";
                respContent += book.title;
                respContent += " do listy ksiazek oczekujacych na zatwierdzenie!</span>";

                $("#bookResponse").html(respContent);
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

HTTP request:

```
POST /ksiazka/book/new.json HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 100
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8080/ksiazka/book/new
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2
Cookie: SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=bWFjaWVqbWlzMkBnbWFpbC5jb206MTQxNzUzODc3ODU4NjpjYjY3YTZiMWYyMGJjODYyMDYxMDQyNDIyN2NmNjQ3Mg; JSESSIONID=c5a72acb3bd1a165f9c2d705a199
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Content-Language: 
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 04 Nov 2014 19:49:08 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1105
```

Any ideas how to solve this? 
As a base I used [this](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/) tutorial. I searched and read most of threads with 400 Bad Request error but it didn't solve my problem.

Edit:
Book class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Book")
    @Indexed
    public class Book {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "bookId")
        private Long id;
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
        private String title;
        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String ISBN;
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
        private String author;
        private String publisher;
        @Column(length = 1000)
        private String description;
        private int publicationYear;
        private int pages;
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private BookStatus bookStatus;
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "booksWant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>(0);
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<UserBook> bookList = new ArrayList<UserBook>(0);

        public Book(String title, String ISBN, String author, String publisher, String description,
                    int publicationYear, int pages, BookStatus bookStatus) {
            this.title = title;
            this.ISBN = ISBN;
            this.author = author;
            this.publisher = publisher;
            this.description = description;
            this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
            this.pages = pages;
            this.bookStatus = bookStatus;
        }
   getters and setters

    }
```

Edit2:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@page language="Java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<tiles:insertDefinition name="template">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="content">

        <h2>book/newBook.jsp</h2>

        <div id="bookResponse">

        </div>
        <div>
            Add a book to system:
        </div>
        <div>
            <sf:form id="addBook" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/book/new" modelAttribute="book">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>isbn: </label></td>
                        <td><sf:input path="ISBN" id="ISBN" /></td>
                        <td><sf:errors path="ISBN" cssClas="error" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Autor: </label></td>
                        <td><sf:input path="author" id="author" /></td>
                        <td><sf:errors path="author" cssClas="error" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Tytul: </label></td>
                        <td><sf:input path="title" id="title" /></td>
                        <td><sf:errors path="title" cssClas="error" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Opis: </label></td>
                        <td><sf:textarea path="description" id="description" /></td>
                        <td><sf:errors path="description" cssClas="error" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Ilosc stron: </label></td>
                        <td><sf:input path="pages" id="pages" /></td>
                        <td><sf:errors path="pages" cssClas="error" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Rok wydawania: </label></td>
                        <td><sf:input path="publicationYear" id="publicationYear" /></td>
                        <td><sf:errors path="publicationYear" cssClas="error" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Wydawca: </label></td>
                        <td><sf:textarea path="publisher" id="publisher" /></td>
                        <td><sf:errors path="publisher" cssClas="error" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Dodaj" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </sf:form>
        </div>

    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

Comment: Can you also show the Book model class?

Comment: What view technology are you using?

Comment: Why your HTTP request is generating `/ksiazka/book/new.json`, see the `.json`, there is no `@RequestMapping` to handle that theoretically.
Can you post the .jsp file too?

Comment: Changed mapping to `/ksiazka/book/new` but still I got the same error. Included .jsp file in the first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. Here is what I did in order to make it work:
Firstly I changed dependency to jackson2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I annotated my Book class with @JsonProperty and @JsonIgnore. Here is my updated Book class

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="Book")
    @Indexed
    public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "bookId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @JsonProperty("ISBN")
    private String ISBN;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @JsonProperty("author")
    private String author;
    @JsonProperty("publisher")
    private String publisher;
    @Column(length = 1000)
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty("publicationYear")
    private int publicationYear;
    @JsonProperty("pages")
    private int pages;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private BookStatus bookStatus;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "booksWant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>(0);
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<UserBook> bookList = new ArrayList<UserBook>(0);

    public Book(String title, String ISBN, String author, String publisher, String description,
                int publicationYear, int pages, BookStatus bookStatus) {
        this.title = title;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.description = description;
        this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.bookStatus = bookStatus;
    }
     getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "'contentType: 'application/json'," from the ajax call

Comment: When I do this I have 415 Unsupported Media and its fine, because Content-Type attribute is different than `application/json`.

Comment: You need to change (a)RequestBody added before Book object to (a)ModelAttribute in the controller. In your case, you actually want to bind the fields in the JSP page with the relative variable in the Book object while posting a request. So that's what (a)ModelAttribute does. What (a)RequestBody does is in fact to convert the data from the page to a n object, like a String. What I suggest in the first comment to because when specify the contentType, ajax call actually uses Request payload to post the request.Keep it default will post form data to server side, you can see that via Chrome Devtool