# Validating model - received from JSON (spring mvc) - good practices

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a simple POJO class (models) created from JSON format (received from frontend).

What is good approach to validate these values ? For example if number is not null, if is it number (nor string), etc.

Comment: Maybe check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312554/how-to-use-javax-validation-and-json-request-in-spring-4-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for validate your attributes the annotation @Valid in your RestController and put @NotNull or @NotEmpty in your Model. For exemple:

```
  @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/book")
    public class BookController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> save(@Valid @RequestBody Book book){
            //save book
        }
    }

   @Entity
   public class Book{
     @NotEmpty(message="msg")
     private String name;
   }
```

Comment: Is there any way to in case of unsuccessful validation send (answer )error to frontend

Comment: you can use something likie this:

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute @Valid T t, final BindingResult bindingResult,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, Model model, SessionStatus status) {
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
model.addAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.strategy", bindingResult);
model.addAttribute(getModelName(), t);
return getFormPageName();
}